# How does UITextField handle french characters?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nsstring, uitextfield

I have a UITextField that takes input for both english and french.
After I type french accents chars for example àÂèÎôÛç, and log the string, it looks like this:
\M-C\240\M-C\M^B\M-C\M-(\M-C\M^N\M-C\M-4\M-C\M^[\M-C\M-'
I've done a little research, but couldn't find what kind of encoding this is.

What kind of encoding is this?
How people normally handle encoding of special character?

Comment: Show how you log the string. Xcode has a bad habit of logging things poorly. The string certainly doesn't actually contain that weird encoding.

Comment: i think it is utf8..!!!

Comment: @rmaddy You are correct! I run the app with xcode, and in the console it looks good. Before I was only using Debug Log because of network restriction of company. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The return type of the [`text` method of `UITextField`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitextfield/1619635-text?language=objc) is [`NSString`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring?language=objc) which according to the documentation is:

> An NSString object encodes a Unicode-compliant text string, represented as a sequence of UTF–16 code units. All lengths, character indexes, and ranges are expressed in terms of 16-bit platform-endian values, with index values starting at 0.

So it is just Unicode and the Xcode console just isn't printing it correctly.